# Libgdx iOS is my app really is 98.3 MB?

Tags: ios, libgdx

So im using LibGDX  and I have exported the iOS project and it generated 3 files:

- `IOSLauncher`- 55.9 MB
- `IOSLauncher.app.dSYM` - 24.5 MB
- `IOSLauncher.ipa`  - 17.9 MB

total of 98.3 MB

My questions are:

- Is my app gonna be 98.3 MB?!
- If so, how I can reduce this size? im
  using mobidevelop robovm fork

the android version is roughly 10 MB ... now I can live with a few more MB but 98.3 MB is just too much for my simple game

Comment: Do you use box2D? It adds more then 40mb to your file size.

Comment: @Madmenyo I didnt the only extension I used is freetype

Comment: I never build on iOS but this might be useful to you: http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9002